# Image not displaying when shared on Facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I have a small Rails application which I occasionally share on Facebook.  Despite there being images on the front page, If I share the this, no thumbnails are displayed.  Is there anything I need to do to make sure Facebook can pick up the images, or is there any reason why it wouldn't pick something up from my page?  [Link to my website](http://www.pastonpaper.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `og:image` you're defining - [according to the FB Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pastonpaper.com%2F) - http://pastonpaper.com/logo.jpg is 404ing. Once you fix that and any other errors, you should be good to go.